# How to change a specif tags inside another?

Tags: java, regex

How could I replace all the P tags inside the TD tag without change the P tag outside the TD?

```
<p align="justify">Example 01</p>

<td style="text-align: center;" width="104">
<p align="center"><strong>My Strong</strong></p>

<p align="center"><strong>Anoter content</strong></p>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;" width="153">
<p align="center"><strong>lorem</strong></p>
</td>
```

I am expecting to get this:

```
<p align="justify">Example 01</p>

<td style="text-align: center;" width="104">
<span align="center"><strong>My Strong</strong></span>

<span align="center"><strong>Anoter content</strong></span>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;" width="153">
<span align="center"><strong>lorem</strong></span>
</td>
```

Comment: Change them to what? What do you expect your output to be?

Comment: What language/tool/regex flavor?

Comment: @Soviut I will update my question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @StevenDoggart I am using regex with java.

Comment: Why not use a tool like jsoup for this over a regex?  Regex is generally the wrong tool for dom traversal:  https://jsoup.org/

Comment: You're welcome @HigorMorais -- Glad I could be of service.